# Obtaining the second item inside a list of lists

Tags: scheme, lisp

I have a list generated via a nested `cons` that creates a structure like this - I've created a example list below.

`(define lst '(((name . test) . 15)  ))`

I wish to later use `assq` to filter for the name and then access the value for each name. For instance, in the example above, I want to be able to do something of the fashion (pseudocode):

`if (cdr (assq 'name lst2) == test, print the value [15]`

How do I do this? I can only do `(assq 'name (car (lst)))` to get back the correct name but then I lose access to the value 15

Comment: `(assoc '(name . test) lst)`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own `assoc`-like procedure.  Either one that has a key function to extract the thing you want to compare, or one that has a general test function that can do that, or both.  Here's one which allows a general test function:

```
(define (asst o l test)
  ;; test is called on o and the element of l in that order
  (if (null? l)
      #f
      (let ((f (car l))
            (r (cdr l)))
        (if (test o f)
            f
            (asst o r test)))))
```

And now

```
> (asst 'name '(((name . test) . 15))
        (lambda (o el)
          (eqv? o (car (car el)))))
'((name . test) . 15)
```

If you want to do a more general test on the list then there's a common function called `find` which will do this.  [`find` is defined in SRFI 1](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#find), but it is easy to implement:

```
(define (find pred? l)
  (cond
    ((null? l)
     #f)
    ((pred? (first l))
     (first l))
    (else
     (find pred? (rest l)))))
```

Given `find` it's then easy to write a function which looks for, for instance, a specific key and value in your structure:

```
(define (findfv l field value)
  (find (λ (e)
          (and (eqv? (car (car e)) field)
               (eqv? (cdr (car e)) value)))
        l))
```

And now

```
> (findfv '(((name . fred) . 12) ((feature . legs) 8) ((name . josephine) . 15)) 'name 'josephine)
'((name . josephine) . 15)
> (findfv '(((name . fred) . 12) ((feature . legs) 8) ((name . josephine) . 15)) 'feature 'legs)
'((feature . legs) 8)
```

---

(In CL the provided `assoc` function allows both test and key options)